# How to hide the legend in chart.js in a react project?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js

I am trying to hide the legend of my chart created with Chart.js.

According to the official documentation (https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/legend.html), to hide the legend, the `display` property of the `options.display` object must be set to `false`.

I have tried to do it in the following way:

```
const options = {
    legend: {
        display: false,
    }
};
```

But it doesn't work, my legend is still there. I even tried this other way, but unfortunately, without success.

```
const options = {
    legend: {
        display: false,
            labels: {
                display: false
            }
        }
    }
};
```

This is my full code.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Line } from "react-chartjs-2";
import numeral from 'numeral';

const options = {
    legend: {
        display: false,
    },
    elements: {
        point: {
            radius: 1,
        },
    },
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    tooltips: {
        mode: "index",
        intersect: false,
        callbacks: {
            label: function (tooltipItem, data) {
                return numeral(tooltipItem.value).format("+0,000");
            },
        },
    },
    scales: {
        xAxes: [
            {
                type: "time",
                time: {
                    format: "DD/MM/YY",
                    tooltipFormat: "ll",
                },
            },
        ],
        yAxes: [
            {
                gridLines: {
                    display: false,
                },
                ticks: {
                    callback: function(value, index, values) {
                        return numeral(value).format("0a");
                    },
                },
            },
        ],
    },
};

const buildChartData = (data, casesType = "cases") => {
    let chartData = [];
    let lastDataPoint;

    for(let date in data.cases) {
        if (lastDataPoint) {
            let newDataPoint = {
                x: date,
                y: data[casesType][date] - lastDataPoint
            }
            chartData.push(newDataPoint);
        }
        lastDataPoint = data[casesType][date];
    }
    return chartData;
};

function LineGraph({ casesType }) {

    const [data, setData] = useState({});

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async() => {
            await fetch("https://disease.sh/v3/covid-19/historical/all?lastdays=120")
            .then ((response) => {
                return response.json();
            })
            .then((data) => {
                let chartData = buildChartData(data, casesType);
                setData(chartData);
            });
        };
        fetchData();
    }, [casesType]);

    return (
        <div>
            {data?.length > 0 && (
            <Line 
                data={{
                    datasets: [
                        {
                            backgroundColor: "rgba(204, 16, 52, 0.5)",
                            borderColor: "#CC1034",
                            data: data
                        },
                    ],
                }}
                options={options}
            />
            )}
        </div>
    );
}

export default LineGraph;
```

Could someone help me? Thank you in advance!

PD: Maybe is useful to try to find a solution, but I get 'undefined' in the text of my legend and when I try to change the text like this, the text legend still appearing as 'Undefindex'.

```
const options = {
    legend: {
        display: true,
        text: 'Hello!'
    }
};
```

[image]

Answer (score 12):

As described in the documentation you linked the namespace where the legend is configured is: `options.plugins.legend`, if you put it there it will work:

```js
var options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        borderColor: 'pink'
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    plugins: {
      legend: {
        display: false
      }
    }
  }
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.5.0/chart.js"></script>
</body>
```

On another note, a big part of your options object is wrong, its in V2 syntax while you are using v3, please take a look at the [migration guide](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/getting-started/v3-migration.html)

Reason why you get `undefined` as text in your legend is, is because you dont supply any `label` argument in your dataset.

Comment: Do you think I could downgrade the version of my chart js? Should editing my `package-lock.json` file be enough? @LeeLenalee

Comment: yes but you need to edit it in your normal `package.json` file by setting the number to `2.9.4` and then run your install command again. You can also uninstall chart.js and then run the install command but specify the version like so: `npm i chart.js@2.9.4`

Answer (score 9):

in the newest versions this code works fine

```js
const options = {
    plugins: {
      legend: {
        display: false,
      },
    },
  };
return <Doughnut data={data} options={options} />;
```

Comment: For whoever is looking for an up-to-date solution for React, this is it.

Answer (score 0):

Import your options value inside the charts component like so:

```
const options = {
    legend: {
      display: false
    }
};

<Line data={data} options={options} />
```

Comment: This is what OP has in his question which is not working

Comment: Using ChartJS4/React ChartJS 2:
It should be `options = { plugins: { legend: { display: false, } } }` -- in other words, options -> plugins -> legend, _not_ options -> legend